# jQuery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Is it possible to hide filters from certain columns only with jQuery tablesorter?
First three columns don't need a filter(they only make the table longer).

```
<table id="userTable"  class="table-sorter table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Login
            </th>
            <th>Email
            </th>
            <th>Company
            </th>
            <th>LastName
            </th>
            <th>FirstName
            </th>
            <th>ZipCode
            </th>
            <th>City
            </th>
            <th class="filter-select" data-placeholder="Select">Country
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by hiding the first four input fields.

```
// remove filters from first 4 columns
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            $('input[data-column='+i+']').hide();
        }
```

Don't know if this is the right way.But it works.
Grts
Danny

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember jQuery having a native tablesorter plugin, so I think your using this one: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Which if you look down towards the config options. You will see 'headers' can be used to manually disable sorting on headers via passing options: `{ 0: { sorter: false}, 1: {sorter: false} }` which will disable sorting on the first 2 columns.

Just read that doc over and you should get it.

Comment: This is indeed the plugin i use, but the problem is with the filter widget,
i only need to apply filters for certain columns, and not the first three,
there is also an attribute filter: false ,but the problem is the input fields for the first three columns are disabled, but the fields themselves keep visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide them then you can do:

```
// Index starts at 0 so you want to hide elem 0, 1, 2 and 3
$('input:lt(4)').hide();
```

This hides the first for inputs. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VWkJZ/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using my fork of [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) with the filter widget. So all you would need to do to disable a filter for a specific column is add the class name `filter-false` to the `th`:

```
<table id="userTable"  class="table-sorter table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="filter-false">
                <input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th class="filter-false"></th>
            <th class="filter-false"></th>
            <th class="filter-false"></th>
            <th>Login</th>
```

What that does is it still adds the filter to the filter row, but the input is disabled. Then all you would need to do is add this css:

```
/* hide disabled filter inputs */
.tablesorter-filter.disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/217/) of what I described above.